# Manage auto increment column values in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I have a table in which auto incremental sequence is defined for a key column.

**Problem Statement-**

**Source_table** has column **ID** with **values** `101, 102, 103` so on and **Destination_table** has column **ID** with **values** `1201,1202,1203`.. and is in **incremental** form.

`Source_table`

[image: Source_table]

`Destination_table`

[image: Destination_table]

Now, in **Mosaic** I am able to read the data from the **Source_table**, but while writing into the **Destination table**, the **values** of `Destination_table.ID` gets overwritten by the `Source_table.ID` **values**.

Is there any way that I can **preserve** the sequence of my **Destination_table** in **Mosaic**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Skip Insert` and `Skip Update` functionalities available in the **writer node** for `Upsert` **write mode**, in which it will skip the sequence coming from the **input** and preserve the sequence at the **destination** column.

To achieve this, in the **Writer Node Configuration** menu, select the **Write Mode** as Upsert and drag in the columns you wish to preserve the **sequence** for to the `Skip Insert` and `Skip Update`, as shown below:

[image: skip insert and update functionality of mosaic decisions writer node]